# Write json variables from selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to write two variables values from selenium test script in json but my code updating my whole json instead of update two variable values which i want.

In the code i am getting two variable values run time and need to write these values in json but its updating whole json instead of two defined variable values, please suggest

```
List<String> GCDetails = editOrderPage.getGCDetails("USD$ 50.00");
String gNo = GCDetails.get(0),
        pNo = GCDetails.get(1);

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("Code", pNo);
obj.put("Number", gNo);

try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("src" + File.separator + "\\main\\resources\\TestFiles\\Card.json")) {
    file.write(obj.toJSONString());
    file.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.print(obj);
}
```

Comment: Please add some code so people can help you

Comment: What do you mean by "its updating whole json instead of two defined variable values"?